# Creating Random Matrix With Equal No of 1's and 0's in python

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to make a random matrix with equal no of 1 and 0 is there any other optimized way of doing that

```
import numpy as np
N = 50
X=10
arr = np.array([0] * N + [1] * N)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
arr=arr.reshape(X,X)
print(arr)
```

Is there a more optimized way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you looking for a "more optimized solution"? Are you running into performance issues?

Comment: Is it essential that there are the same number of 0s and 1s? Or do you just need each entry to be either 0 or 1 with equal probability?

Comment: A simple way to write what you need is `arr = (np.random.permutation(100) % 2).reshape(10, 10)`. Whether that's faster or not, I have no idea ...

Comment: In your solution, you could use `np.ones()` and `np.zeros()` to create initial arrays, but other than that (fairly minor point) your solution seems efficient and readable to me.

Comment: @MarkDickinson It is, at least for large arrays. `&1` instead of `%2` is even faster

Comment: @Akavall On my machine, with N=1,000,000 the permutation solution is almost 20 times faster.

Comment: Presumably you're doing this in a loop, many times? (Else I wonder where the need for an optimised solution comes from.) Does the size `N` change each time, or do you need many example arrays for each `N`? If the latter, you don't need to worry about the cost of setting up `arr` in the first place; only the cost of the shuffling is important.